# How to find remainder of this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

If the equation $x^6+3x^4-2x^2+3x+2$ is divided by $x-1$, then what will be the remainder?

I put value of x as 1 in the equation and thus I get the answer 7.

My answer is correct but I am looking for basic concept.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking why plugging in $x=1$ correctly gives the remainder?  Remember definition of quotient and remainder: $f(x)=q(x)(x-1)+r(x)$ where $r(x)$ is a polynomial of degree strictly less than $(x-1)$ or is zero, i.e. it is a constant in this specific case.  If you plug in $x=1$ the term $q(x)(x-1)$ completely disappears.  If you want to use a longer more tedious method, you can use the division algorithm to perform polynomial long division and arrive at the answer that way.  The process is essentially the same as long division for integers.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the [polynomial remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem), the proof of which basically just involves rewriting the polynomial as $f(x) = q(x)(x - a) + r$ and noting that therefore $f(a) = r$.